# Using the Drupal Cache API for Drupal Entity Caching

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-10

I am reading up on the Cache API, and have a question about caching users (or objects in general) in the DB, i.e. the `cache_default` MySQL table.

Please consider the following simple function to retrieve a `User` object (I know this type of code should probably live in a custom service, but am using a function here, just for clarity):

```
<?php 

/** 
 * Get a user object
 * @param Integer
 * @return User 
 */
function get_user_data($uid)
{
    if ($uid) {
        $cache_id = 'my_user:' . $uid;
        $user = NULL;
        if ($cache = \Drupal::cache()->get($cache_id)) {
            // Read user object from the default cache.
            $user = $cache->data; 
        }
        else {
            // user not found in the cache.
            $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);

            // Cache tags from User object, to tell Drupal to invalidate the cache
            // data after any change to the user.
            $user_cache_tags = $user->getCacheTags();

            // Store a serialized user object in the default cache.
            \Drupal::cache()->set($cache_id, $user, Cache::PERMANENT, $user_cache_tags);
        }
        return $user; 
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

My goal is to cache a Drupal `User` object, that also depends on large amounts of data in multiple profiles (using the Profiles module).

The `User` for my use case might actually require more properties, or some way to an interface with `Profile` objects, and thus may need to extend `User` (a "MyUser" class etc), but the design of our objects is out of scope for this question.

My question is:

**Does the above code accomplish anything useful?  (Or Is Drupal already caching `User` objects somewhere, and the above code accomplishes nothing?)**

Also assume for my use case:

- I am not able to use Redis or Memcached.
- My Drupal application must rely on many very cumbersome database queries (to read user tables, profile tables) every time I need to
  gather user data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Interesting question... I did find [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/597236) that reports entity cache was added to core in D8